# Creating a map of a place

Tags: civil-engineering

I would like to know what are the tools and the techniques to create a map as precise as possible of a place, typically interior, and also, in certains reasonable way, quickly.

That is, a 2D representation of the room and the things inside. I don't care about pillows or small ornaments, or even chairs, but big things like cupboards or fixed things like toilets. I don't care about the details, a rectangle for a bath tub would be good.

Also, as a corollary question, does some AI exists such as if you take some photos of a room from different positions (maybe on top of a ladder), it can triangulate the objects and create a 2D map from above (aside real measures, but only relative ones)?

Sorry if this isn't much in topic, it's impossible put these questions in search engine and obtain relevant results (like almost always nowadays). Also, it should be evident, I come from a different background. Thanks very much.

EDIT 2023-12-26: thanks everyone, it seems I can only accept a single answer, but all of them were useful.

Comment: Laser based void scanners have been used to map underground voids since the early 2000s. They can be used inside buildings as well as underground: [Void Scanner 1](https://www.maptek.com/video/i-site-8200-laser-scanner/), [Void Scanner 2](https://optron.com/carlson/portfolio/void-scanner/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

House-selling agencies do something even better than what you're asking about. They can take a walk through the house with a video camera with accelerometer (to keep track of pan and tilt, etc.). The files are compiled back at the office and merged into one 3D representation that potential buyers can "walk-through".

A search for "3D room scanner" will get you some results including mobile phone apps. [Scan Room to D3 using your Phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWT7hAZFkEc&t=455s&ab_channel=Nate%27sStudioDesk), for example, shows how this is done. You'll end up with a 3D model and you could easily just use a birds-eye view for your 2D representation.

Answer (score 1):

There are services that use a LIDAR (I think) to create a 3D image of a room, this data ("point cloud") can then be given to a CAD person to transform into a good plan. At least where I work this has not yet been done automatically. Laser scan should be a relevant search term.

If the shape is reasonable simple you can take a laser or tape measure and draw the building to scale yourself. Took me (I think) 1 hour to measure a ~110m³ apartment with 7 or 8 rooms, plus half again the time for drawing (at accuracy in the cm region at best!).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 3d models from 2d shots has been available for decades now, but try https://lifehacker.com/magicplan-creates-a-floor-plan-with-your-phone-s-camera-1614766960 for what you are actually talking about. I have not tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Для таких задач я использую Iphone с функцией лидар и приложение Polycam.

*Edit - Translated using Google Translate*

For such tasks, I use an iPhone with lidar function and the Polycam app.